# Prevent arrow keys from opening autocomplete menu

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I am using cx4a.org's Auto Complete mode with GNU Emacs 24.3.1, and following options:

```
(setq ac-ignore-case nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map "\r" nil)
(setq ac-auto-start 2)
```

When I type a prefix at the end of a line, and wish to move down a line (pressing the Down arrow key), instead of moving the cursor, the auto-completion menu pops up. For example (in Python)

```
def passing():
    print("passing")

def passed():
    print("passed")

# insert new function here

def willpass():
    print("will pass")
```

When I insert a dummy function (that just passes) at the comment location, after typing `pass`, I press the Down arrow key (wanting to move down a line), but instead, the menu pops up with options "pass, passed, passing".

How do I prevent this menu from popping up in this usage example? I tried re-mapping `<up>` and `<down>` in both ac-mode-map and ac-menu-map to nil, with no effect.

Note: Pressing C-n instead of Down does not open the menu, but it feels unnatural. And rebinding Down to (next-line) did nothing.

Also, I could sidestep this issue by setting `ac-delay` to 1 and setting the trigger-key to Tab, but this set of options has other drawbacks that led me to revert back to the first set of options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
(define-key ac-completing-map [down] nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map [up] nil)
```

And actually most people prefer <kbd>C-n</kbd> to <kbd>down</kbd>.
Did you swap Ctrl and Caps?

Comment: Thank you! It just happened to be the one map I didn't try out :( I did not swap Ctrl and Caps, and I think I'll be using Tab to move down the menu.